# CouchDB won't let me DELETE. I think I have users set up correctly

Tags: couchdb

I created a database "my_new_database" and "albums", neither of which I can DELETE. I believe I am still in "ADMIN" party mode. To demonstrate my issue Ill just post some info below.

First here is to show couchdb running ( started using the SystemV script via **service** )

```
$ ps aux | grep couch
couchdb   2939  0.0  0.2 108320  1528 ?        S    20:45   0:00 /bin/sh -e /usr/bin/couchdb -a /etc/couchdb/default.ini -a /etc/couchdb/local.ini -b -r 0 -p /var/run/couchdb/couchdb.pid -o /dev/null -e /dev/null -R
couchdb   2950  0.0  0.1 108320   732 ?        S    20:45   0:00 /bin/sh -e /usr/bin/couchdb -a /etc/couchdb/default.ini -a /etc/couchdb/local.ini -b -r 0 -p /var/run/couchdb/couchdb.pid -o /dev/null -e /dev/null -R
couchdb   2951  4.8  2.3 362168 14004 ?        Sl   20:45   0:00 /usr/lib64/erlang/erts-5.8.5/bin/beam -Bd -K true -A 4 -- -root /usr/lib64/erlang -progname erl -- -home /usr/local/var/lib/couchdb -- -noshell -noinput -sasl errlog_type error -couch_ini /etc/couchdb/default.ini /etc/couchdb/local.ini /etc/couchdb/default.ini /etc/couchdb/local.ini -s couch -pidfile /var/run/couchdb/couchdb.pid -heart
couchdb   2959  0.0  0.0   3932   304 ?        Ss   20:45   0:00 heart -pid 2951 -ht 11
ec2-user  2963  0.0  0.1 103424   828 pts/1    S+   20:45   0:00 grep couch
```

Here is the output of the ".couch" databases I have ( shown for user ownership and permissions)

```
$ ls -lat /var/lib/couchdb
-rw-r--r--  1 couchdb couchdb   23 Oct 11 20:45 couch.uri
drwxr-xr-x  3 couchdb couchdb 4096 Oct 11 19:35 .
-rw-r--r--  1 couchdb couchdb   79 Oct 11 19:35 database2.couch
-rwxrwxrwx  1 couchdb couchdb   79 Oct 11 19:00 my_new_database.couch
-rw-r--r--  1 couchdb couchdb 4182 Oct  4 21:52 albums.couch
-rw-r--r--  1 couchdb couchdb   79 Oct  4 21:42 albums-backup.couch
-rw-r--r--  1 couchdb couchdb 4185 Oct  4 21:30 _users.couch
drwxr-xr-x 18 root    root    4096 Oct  4 20:58 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Oct  4 18:34 .delete
```

Here is my first attempt to DELETE

```
$ curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:5984/my_new_database
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a server admin."}
```

And my second attempt using an authenticated user.

```
$ curl -X DELETE http://brian:brian@127.0.0.1:5984/my_new_database
{"error":"error","reason":"eacces"}
```

The username/password of brian/brian was added to the [admin] section of /etc/couchdb/local.ini

Here is the output of my "_users" file. The "key" and "id" fields confuse me.

```
$ curl -X GET http://brian:brian@127.0.0.1:5984/_users/_all_docs
{"total_rows":1,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"_design/_auth","key":"_design/_auth","value":{"rev":"1-c44fb12a2676d481d235523092e0cec4"}}
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your CouchDB after you added to user to local.ini? If so, has the password in the file been hashed or is it readable?

Generally your file permissions look OK, so I can't tell what exactly causes the error. For a quick fix you can simply delete the .couch file, though.

Comment: I did try restarting with no luck
`$ sudo service couchdb restart
Stopping couchdb:                                          [  OK  ]
Starting couchdb:                                          [  OK  ]


$ curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:5984/albums-backup
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a server admin."} 
`

Comment: Let me add to this, because I didn't include authentication. When i run `curl -X DELETE http://brian:brian@127.0.0.1:5984/albums-backup` I receive `{"error":"error","reason":"eacces"}`

My /var/lib/couchdb/_users.couch file has some encrypted strings along with JS looking functions. Thank you, skoegl

Answer (score 0):

This question is really old, but since I got bitten by this today and this is where Google led me, I thought I'd share my solution for others that stumble here.  In my case, my Couch lib directory (`/usr/local/var/lib/couchdb` for me) had a directory called `.delete` that was owned by root.  Changing the owner to couchdb let me delete databases again.